# MySQL query does not run in SQLite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

```
SELECT MAX( PRC_MIN_LENGTH ) PRC_MIN_LENGTH, MIN( PRC_MAX_LENGTH ) PRC_MAX_LENGTH, MAX( PRC_MIN_WIDTH ) PRC_MIN_WIDTH, MIN( PRC_MAX_WIDTH ) PRC_MAX_WIDTH
FROM (

SELECT PRDT_PRICE_CODE, MIN( PRC_MIN_LENGTH ) PRC_MIN_LENGTH, MAX( PRC_MAX_LENGTH ) PRC_MAX_LENGTH, MIN( PRC_MIN_WIDTH ) PRC_MIN_WIDTH, MAX( PRC_MAX_WIDTH ) PRC_MAX_WIDTH
FROM PRODUCT_PRICE_INFO
WHERE PRDT_PRICE_CODE
IN (

SELECT PRDT_PRICE_CODE
FROM PRODUCT
WHERE PRODUCT_ID =1
UNION SELECT PRDT_PRICE_CODE
FROM PRODUCT_OPTION
WHERE PROD_OPT_ID
IN (
'1',  '101',  '201',  '303',  '401'
)
)
AND CURDATE( ) 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
AND DATE_ADD( CURDATE( ) , INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) 
GROUP BY PRDT_PRICE_CODE
)PRC_RANGE
```

This query is running in MySQL database but not in SQLite.

Where is the mistake and how can I fix this?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: near "1": syntax error:

Comment: I'm thinking that perhaps `INTERVAL` isn't working in `sqlite`, read up on http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html and try to find a replacement.

Comment: Checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033242/sqlite3-date-and-interval-functions

Comment: The `group by` also seems dubious. I don't think SQLite allows for a "loose" (aka invalid) `group by` with indeterminate results.

Comment: I have changed CURDATE() and INTERVAL  into date('now,'+1 day').error is cleared but value is empty.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQLite allows non-grouped, non-aggregated columns, and even guarantees a useful result if a single MIN()/MAX() is used (where MySQL would return a randow row's value). But in this query, this isn't any difference.

Comment: Do not change the question; this would invalidate any existing answers. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite uses different [date functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).
You would have to write the date comparison like this:

```
...
AND date('now') BETWEEN date('now', '-1 days')
                    AND date('now', '+1 days')
...
```

(This is a faithful translation, and will make the query run; but it's doubtful that this query does what you want in either MySQL or SQLite.)

Comment: I have changed like above.but the result is empty,how to solve this.